# php cannot post on html submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How could i write an ajax script to call my PHP file from the HTML?

I have attempted the following ajax but it doesn't work. i just want it to simply call the userlogin.php once the user clicks on the submit button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272991/php-cannot-post-error-running-xampp this person had the same problem

Comment: `url: 'userlogin.php',`?

Comment: remove the inline onlick `onclick="click_button_login()"` also add `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: will i add  e.preventDefault(); to the button?

Comment: @user20051996 what error are you having

Comment: Cannot POST /http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/xampp/htdocs/xampp/glove_project_php/www/userlogin.php ..... i have had this error for days

Comment: check this demo https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/8uv89uq7/

Comment: thank you all for your help. @guradio i have changed my code but still no luck, once i click on the login button nothing happens. the same page stays open :(

Comment: @user20051996 Please check your firebug when you click on submit, if ajax is getting called properly or not

Comment: it will not change to another page ajax works on back ground check your dev tools > network > xhr for result from ajax request @user20051996

Comment: method POST status displays OK, no errors to show

Comment: I think your missing this  "});"  after return false

Answer (score 0):

Change as follows

```
  <form Name ="form1" Method ="POST" action = "" id="form1">
```

Change `url: 'userlogin.php'`

Comment: have changed this, it still gave me the same error :(

Comment: Please check `console`  error details and post here.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ..... http://127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/xampp/htdocs/xampp/glove_project_php/www/userlogin.php

Comment: it seems like my application cannot find the php file even though it is in the exact file it's searching for

Comment: @user20051996 change the url in ajax firstly, and then please change data type to json. Also just one thing for calling ajax on submit you also have to call validation function to check form and on success call ajax. Either use HTML 5 required attribute

Comment: Have you changed `form action = ""`

Comment: i have changed form action="" and the url but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing input type="submit" with input type="button" and instead of binding form submit event, bind the click event to button for making ajax call to post data.

Comment: i have changed this to button. what do you mean by 'bind the click event'?

Comment: Click event bind means handling click event. Make ajax call on button click instead of submit as below:
$( "#submit" ).bind( "click", function() {
  //Replace your ajax code with comment
});

You can learn more about event binding on http://api.jquery.com/bind/.

Comment: Check newer answer

Answer (score 0):

Make ajax call on button click instead of submit as below:

```
$( "#submit" ).bind( "click", function() {
   //Replace your ajax code with comment
});
```

You can learn more about event binding on http://api.jquery.com/bind/.

Comment: changed this, still staying on the same page once i click on the submit button

Comment: Do you want to navigate to next page on submit?

Comment: yeah i cant to navigate to the next page if the users details are correct, otherwise they should remain on the same page. how could i go about doing this?

Comment: If you just want to redirect to another page on post, you don't need ajax. You can use html form submit. 
To use ajax submit, you need to return HTML content from server(PHP) instead of trying to redirect. In PHP, you should return HTML content. And in  Javascript Ajax success, you need to set received html response in div/body of page.

Answer (score 0):

Your script sectio, you have missed to close one function with '});'

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('form[name=form1]').submit(function(){
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    beforeSend: function(){
       // myApp.showIndicator();
    },
    sucess: function(data) {
        //myApp.hideIndicator();
        //myApp.alert(data);
    }
  });
  return false;
 }); // this is what your are missing in your code
});
```

Comment: @user20051996 Please the check above let me know if this worked for, just check all the braces are closed correctly

Comment: hi thank you for your help, still getting the same error though 'Cannot POST'

Comment: have you changed the datatype and url ??

Comment: yeah i changed it to my php file and the datatype=json?

Comment: yes like this  dataType: 'json', as I run your it was working okay, what i have changed is, in form i have action to "#" and I have commented the your myApp lines, just check you don't have issue with myApp, and just print $_POST in your ajax files to whether you don't have error in your php code